# substrings between set of delimiters Vice versa

Tags: regex, perl

I use a regexp with a set of delimiters to tokenize a book.

```
my $a='A B?C&D"E.F"G,H;I;J/K/L?M:N';
print $a."\n";
my @b=split( /[ ?&".,;\/]/ , $a );
foreach (@b) {  print"|".$_."|,"; } print"\n";
```

this already works:

```
A B?C&D"E.F"G,H;I;J/K/L?M:N
|A|,|B|,|C|,|D|,|E|,|F|,|G|,|H|,|I|,|J|,|K|,|L|,|M:N|,
```

But what kind of regexp will return only the delimiters from $a to a scalar or list?

```
my $c = $a =~ REGEXP_I_AM_LOOKING_FOR  --> ' ?&".",;;//?'
```

Any hint to do this as simple as possible would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ' ?&".",;;//?:' ov course has to be ' ?&".",;;//?'

Comment: Thank You so far.
I would prefer to use the negated class.
But I got
||,| |,|?|,|&|,|"|,|.|,|"|,|,|,|;|,|;|,|/|,|/|,|?|,
Here the element $c[0] is wrong :-(
Additional: Is it possible to hold the delimiters in a scalar an use the scalar in the Regexp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold the delimiters in a string.

```
my $input = 'A B?C&D"E.F"G,H;I;J/K/L?M:N';
my $delimiters = ' ?&".",;;//?';

my @found_fields = split( /[$delimiters]/, $input );
print "|$_|," foreach (@found_fields);
```

Now you can get just the delimiters seen in a string by using a negated character class, which is just this `[^...]`

```
my @found_delimiters = split( /[^$delimiters]/, $input );
print "|$_|," foreach (@found_delimiters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split on a negated character class `[^...]` ?

```
my @b=split( /[^ ?&".,;\/]/ , $a );
```

Or use a regular expression with the `/g` (global) modifier

```
my @b = /[ ?&".,;\/]/g;
```

Comment: Can one do this by holding the delimiters in a scalar too?

Answer (score 0):

```
# ' ', '?', '&', '"', ...
my @seps = $a =~ /([ ?&".,;\/])/g;
```

or maybe you'd prefer to have:

```
# 'A', ' ', 'B', '?', 'C', ...
my @both = split /([ ?&".,;\/])/, $a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without using one-liner regexp.

```
my @delimiters = ();
while($a =~ /([ ?&\"\.\,\;\/])/g) {
  push(@delimiters, $1);
}
```